# WIFi Authentication with Windows Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, wifi, radius, 802.1

What would you recommend for scenario.

Office with 100 employees multiple device platforms(Apple , Windows and Android).
Existing Windows Active Directory on Windows 2008 but not all devices use this to authenticate (Personal Laptops , guests and Personal phones/tablets).

The desire to connect to the wifi using active directory username and password (NB little to none client side configuration just type username and password and forget about wifi , connecting again at password change)

No captive portal just like connecting to your home wifi.

Ubiquiti Access Points

Comment: What have you tried? WPA2 Enterprise authentication is built for expressly this exact scenario.

Comment: Step-by-step implementation here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721726.aspx

Comment: http://techblog.mirabito.net.au/?p=87 Used This worked well

Answer (score 1):

RADIUS (and NPS, its Windows implementation) is your friend. You can start from here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994700.aspx.

If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask. As it is, this question is *way* too generic to be properly answered.